# how to get data from mongodb of specific user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database in which users can create different topics of different subjects for example science, math, English, etc. my code of topic model is.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    topic: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
   },
   subject: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "user"
   }
});
const Topic = mongoose.model('Topic', topicSchema);
module.exports = Topic;
```

My get API is this

```
const getTopicByUserId = function(req,res) {
    Topic.find({userId: req.params.userId})
    .then(data => {
        var message = "";
        if (data === undefined || data.length == 0) message = "No Topic found!";
        else message = 'Topics successfully retrieved';
        res.status(200).send(data)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send('Some error occured')
    })
}
```

user can add many topics of different subjects and this API gets all topic data of a specific user. In my front end, I have to represent the data according to different subjects created by a specific user. How can I make an API that can get data of different subjects of specific users and will display them in my application?
this is my json object.

```
{ "topic": "Liver",
"subject": "Science" }
```

this is my response

```
{ "topic": "Liver",
"subject": "Science",
"userId": "6230ab6516f17ed82cbce749",
"_id": "623271addac895c8203c608d",
"__v": 0 }
```

Comment: That is grouping of data - by topics and subjects. You may want to include couple of sample documents, in JSON text format, in your question post (so that someone can help).

Comment: Not related to your problem but in order to prevent [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html) you may use library [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) or use `find({userId: JSON.stringify(req.params.userId)})`

Comment: @prasad this is my json object. {
   "topic": "Liver",
   "subject": "Science"
}  this is my response                                                                                                                                                  
 {
    "topic": "Liver",
    "subject": "Science",
    "userId": "6230ab6516f17ed82cbce749",
    "_id": "623271addac895c8203c608d",
    "__v": 0
}